# When to reply 400 Bad Request

Tags: http, 403-forbidden, http-code-400

According to [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), a Web server should reply with status code `400 Bad Request`  if:

"*The request could not be understood by the server due
    to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the
    request without modifications*"

Does that mean only request that violates some HTTP spec?
Or does it include a request that my particular Web app thinks is broken?
When would you reply `400`?

For example, if my Web app expects a query string to always include a "function=..." parameter, would you reply code `400 Bad Request` or `403 Forbidden`? (403 means that *"The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it."*)

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of that header is that the HTTP specification was not followed properly and a required field is missing or bad data is provided. For example a header is missing or invalid characters are used in the request, etc.

Some malformed request exam-ple:

```
GET /images/logo.png HTTP/2 # there is no HTTP 2
POTT /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1 # POTT should be POST
Accept-Language  en-US # Missing colon after header name
```

Your example seems like a legitimate usage of that HTTP response code. However, I suspect this would be better handled in your application. If that parameter is missing you can serve up a much prettier and more through error message. You can also have the page report back to you about the error so you can investigate it if necessary.

Comment: +1 - Thanks I'm working on a site right now that has a bunch of these reported by webmaster tools and was wondering about them. I think a custom 404 page is preferable response from the server.

Comment: Why not a custom 400 page sometimes, and a custom 404 sometimes? (I just tested in my webapp and, on my computer, Chrome & Firefox shows the plain text message in the status 400 page)